# Custom UITableViewCell won't come out of edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I study the Apple sample code Lister,I rewrite the program(remove the container group and `cloudListCoordinator`,and `documentMenu`,`userActivity`,only use the `localDocument` to store the file),It works the same, but I have problem with two custom `UITableViewCell`,one is `listColorCell`,other one is `listItemCell`,I override the `setEditing` method of `TableViewController` as the same with the Apple's sample code,when I press the edit button, the `listColorCell` show in the first row,below is the `listItemCell`,If I don't touch or change the current color of the `listItem`,It can move out of edit mode when I press the done button.

So the problem is ONLY when I touch the `listColorCell` and this make the `listItemCell's` color changed,and press the done button again,the `ListColorCell` and `ListItemCell` seems doesn't move out of edit mode.I check the Storyboard's outlet and content view,use the cavemen debug, still can't find where could be wrong.

1.First,the listItem's color is blue

2.then I press the red `colorView` on the `ListColorCell`, `listItem` color change to red

3.but when I press the done button again,this happen..

Picture Link are: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g58mru17as2h5g6/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E6%88%AA%E5%9B%BE%202015-04-27%2015.53.49.png?dl=0

I'm new to here,hoping somebody can help me..

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion, check whether your controller fit to these requirements :

I use usual UIViewController and it works fine - you need to :

make your controller a delegate of `UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`
implement

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
programmatically add EDIT button - self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
```

(if you add EDIT button from builder you will need to call setEditing : YES manually)

```
 - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }

    - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated 
    {
        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
        [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];
    }

    - (void)tableView 
        :(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath 
        :(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    }

    // do not forget interface in header file

    @interface ContactsController : ViewController<
        UITableViewDelegate,
        UITableViewDataSource>
```

I have given Objective-C code here, You can refer it or you can convert to swift and try

Comment: yes,I just checked again,in viewDidLoad,I have set the editButton,my viewController is a UITableViewController,in tableView(_:commitEditingStyle) I only allow .Delete,I override the setEditing method ,my code in this place are same with the Apple sample code,I wonder where could I did wrong..